# Apply sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler function based on specific group/id in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe given as such:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd


#Create dataset
data = {'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A','A', 'A',
               'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
               'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C',
               'D', 'D', 'D', 'D',
               'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E','E'],
        'cycle': [1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,
                   1,2, 3,4,5,6,
                   1,2, 3, 4, 5,
                  1,2, 3, 4,
                  1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,],
        'Salary': [7, 7, 7,8,9,10,15,
                   4, 4, 4,4,5,6,
                   8,9,10,12,13,
                   8,9,10,11,
                   7, 11,12,13,14,15,],
        'Jobs': [123, 18, 69, 65, 120, 11, 52,
                 96, 120,10, 141, 52,6,
                 101,99, 128, 1, 141,
                 141,123, 12, 66,
                 12, 128, 66, 100, 141, 52,],
        'Days': [123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52,
                 96, 120,120, 141, 52,96,
                 15,123, 128, 120, 141,
                 141,123, 128, 66,
                 123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 52,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("df = \n", df)
```

The above dataframe looks as such:

[image]

Here, I wish to apply [sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) on the columns 'Salary', 'Jobs', 'Days' corresponding to that specific group/id as such:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know how to achieve this task in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to compute minmax scale per group:

```
cols = ['Salary', 'Jobs', 'Days']
minmax_scale = lambda x: (x - x.min(axis=0)) / (x.max(axis=0) - x.min(axis=0))
df[cols] = df.groupby('id')[cols].apply(minmax_scale)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id  cycle    Salary      Jobs      Days
0   A      1  0.000000  1.000000  0.797753
1   A      2  0.000000  0.062500  0.853933
2   A      3  0.000000  0.517857  0.157303
3   A      4  0.125000  0.482143  0.157303
4   A      5  0.250000  0.973214  0.764045
5   A      6  0.375000  0.000000  1.000000  # Max for Days of Group A
6   A      7  1.000000  0.366071  0.000000  # Min for Days of Group A
7   B      1  0.000000  0.666667  0.494382
8   B      2  0.000000  0.844444  0.764045
9   B      3  0.000000  0.029630  0.764045
10  B      4  0.000000  1.000000  1.000000
11  B      5  0.500000  0.340741  0.000000
12  B      6  1.000000  0.000000  0.494382
13  C      1  0.000000  0.714286  0.000000
14  C      2  0.200000  0.700000  0.857143
15  C      3  0.400000  0.907143  0.896825
16  C      4  0.800000  0.000000  0.833333
17  C      5  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
18  D      1  0.000000  1.000000  1.000000
19  D      2  0.333333  0.860465  0.760000
20  D      3  0.666667  0.000000  0.826667
21  D      4  1.000000  0.418605  0.000000
22  E      1  0.000000  0.000000  0.797753
23  E      2  0.500000  0.899225  0.853933
24  E      3  0.625000  0.418605  0.157303
25  E      4  0.750000  0.682171  0.764045
26  E      5  0.875000  1.000000  1.000000
27  E      6  1.000000  0.310078  0.000000
```

As suggested by @mozway, you can use a function or the walrus operator in `lambda` function:

```
# The fastest
def minmax_scale(x):
    xmin = x.min(axis=0)
    xmax = x.max(axis=0)
    return (x - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)

# Average performance, using walrus operator (Python >= 3.8)
minmax_scale = lambda x: (x - (m := x.min(axis=0))) / (x.max(axis=0) - m)

# The slowest
minmax_scale = lambda x: (x - x.min(axis=0)) / (x.max(axis=0) - x.min(axis=0))
```

Comment: With a real function or the walrus operator (`minmax_scale = lambda x: (x - (m:=x.min(axis=0))) / (x.max(axis=0) - m)`) you could reuse the min to avoid computing it twice ;)

Comment: OK for a real function but for lambda, it's really ugly: `minmax_scale = lambda x: (x - (m := x.min(axis=0))) / (x.max(axis=0) - m)`

Comment: But 1/3 less computations!